# @Html.Label value Showing Issue

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0

I have a label tag:

**Case 1:**

```
@Html.Label("Task:", new { @class = "labl" }) 
@Html.Label(@Model.insDetails.cntrctname, new { @class = "pageHeadLabel" })
```

Assigned value of `@Model.insDetails.cntrctname ="Magic lock Test 1.25.18"`

It shows as only `.18` in the resulting page.

**Case 2**:

But If I edit the above as:

```
@Html.Label("Task:", new { @class = "labl" })
@Model.insDetails.cntrctname
```

It shows as `Magic lock Test 1.25.18` on the page.

CSS class pageHeadLabel:

```
.pageHeadLabel {
        color: #990000;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 12px !important;
        display: inline;
        margin-bottom: 2px !important;
        margin-left:3px;
        font-weight: 200;
}
```

I want to correct **case 1**. I need output as:

```
Magic lock Test 1.25.18
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.Label(@Model.insDetails.cntrctname, @Model.insDetails.cntrctname, new { @class = "pageHeadLabel" })
```

In the case of `Label(value, object)`, the value will be interpreted as an identifier.
By writing as `Label(value, value, object)`, the value of the second argument can be output as is.
I do not know what version of the MVC you are using, but perhaps [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.label?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) would be helpful.